# how to send the radio button information in ajax based form in PHP?

Tags: php, html, ajax

I have made an ajax based form for the website, it takes input from the user and sends it to the database. All fields are working fine but there is a problem with the radio buttons in sending the values.
 My code for the ajax is

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 function emp1() {
    .....................
xmlhttp.send("firstname=" + firstname.value + "&lastname=" + lastname.value  + "&company=" + company.value             
    + "&myemail=" + myemail.value
+ "&address=" + address.value
+ "&city=" + city.value
+ "&province=" + province.value
+ "&postalcode=" + postalcode.value
+ "&country=" + country.value
+ "&contact=" + contact.value
+ "&radio1=" + radio1.value
+ "&paymentmethod=" + paymentmethod.value
);
```

}

code for html form for radio buttons is

```
<input type="radio" name="radio1" id="radio1" value="Free Shipping"  onclick="emp1();"> Free Shipping<br />  
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod"  value="abc"  onclick="emp1();">abc
<br />
<input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod" value="def"  onclick="emp1();" onchange="emp1();">def
<br /> 
 <input type="radio" name="paymentmethod" id="paymentmethod" value="ghi"  onclick="emp1();">ghi
```

Any help ... ..
thnx in advance

Comment: Are you opposed to using jQuery?  If not it's extremely easy.

Comment: I'm using the Jquery also..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use something like this to get selected radio button vlaue using javascript inside your `emp1()` function. it will give you selected radio button value.

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByName("paymentmethod");
    for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].checked) {
        var paymentmethod = inputs[i].value;
      }
    }

    alert(paymentmethod);
```

Comment: @mehar , remove alert(paymentmethod) , its just for test. and replace paymentmethod.value with just paymentmethod.